# Милисекунды в ОС linux?

Tags: linux, c, дата, время

Нигде не могу найти как можно было бы вывести миллисекунды в linux?

Пример:

> [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms]

Comment: Стал писать комментарий еще до закрытия. Пусть будет здесь: date +"%F %T.%3N"

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec_get

Comment: Вопрос думаю надо открыть, так как там ответы для виндоус и c++.